# RxAndroid crashes the app although doOnError is implemented

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following code. It's basically an attempt to send all data from a specific SQLite table to DynamoDB:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Area>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Area> subscriber) {
        try {
            for (Area item : areaDao.listAll()) {
                subscriber.onNext(item);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<Area, Observable<Area>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Area> call(Area area) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(area);
        return Observable.just(area);
    }
}).observeOn(
        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
).doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.w("AreaHandler", "Could not upload area", throwable);
    }
}).doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.toast_upload_successful, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).subscribeOn(
        Schedulers.io()
).subscribe(new Action1<Area>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Area area) {
        areaDao.delete(area.getId());
    }
});
```

I'm trying to run it on an emulator with disabled Internet connectivity, and what happens is that the Dynamo client does a couple of (failed) retries, then an exception is thrown and it crashes the app. From what I read in the docs, the exception should be swallowed by doOnError instead of being let out to the wild and killing the process.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grabbing the error in the wrong place. `doOnError` is for side effects. It does not handle the error.

Option 1. Pass in two Action1

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
            .subscribe(
                    new Action1<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Integer integer) {
                            System.out.println(integer);
                        }
                    },
                    new Action1<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                            System.err.print(throwable);
                        }
                    });
```

Option 2: Pass in an Observer

```
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.err.print(throwable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    System.out.println(integer);
                }
            });
```